# Include title and content of one page in another page

Tags: theme-development, title

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090698/wordpress-include-content-of-one-page-in-another) contents of another page can be rendered to another page, but how do I do it for the title too?

Can I just go `$content = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_content);`?

But what do I add at the second argument? From how it looks like, it's an array right?

Which one stores the actual title of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_the_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_title/):

```
$page  = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
$title = get_the_title( $page );
```

You could also use `$page->post_title`, but `get_the_title()` will let plugins access the title, which sometimes quite useful.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer :)
but I am embedding a page to another page.
so it's like a page within a page.

but your answer is helpful, may not be directly to what I wanted but I might try $post->post_title.

Thanks!

Comment: @user2128576 This works with any post object (pages are just special posts). I made an edit to my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Sir!
I have one quick followup question.
is there a way to get page using id?
instead of title?
Since the page I am embedding can change title anytime.
by Id?

Comment: @user2128576 `get_page( 123 );` or `get_post( 123 );`. Both do the same, but `get_page()` is now deprecated, so use `get_post()`.